# Using TensorFlow's preexistent Inception labeler

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, inception

I know I can retrain Inception to label images, but can I just provide an image to a non retrained Inception and get a label back?

Comment: Do you want to fine-tune Inception network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the labels are limited to the ones from ImageNet.